# Bash while loop with substring condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a function with a `while loop` that should run untill it one of the string will be a substring of my second string.
The thing is that the while loop is infinity, and i double checked my condition and it shouldn't go inside the `while loop` with the paramteres that i've entered.
Here is my 2 functions:

```
## check if the client exist
## if exists return 1 else return 0
function isClientExist () {
        clientToCheck=irabinowitz_tlv-cc-lx64_806
        checkClient=$(p4 client -o -t $clientToCheck 2>&1)
        tempStr="doesn\'t exist"
        if [[ $checkClient != *"$tempStr"* ]]; then
                echo The client exist
                flag=1
        else
                echo the client doesnt exist
                clientToCreate=$clientToCheck
                flag=0
        fi
        return $flag
}
## Fixing the client name by appeding  _number to the client name
function fixClientName () {
        echo fixing the client name...
        numToAppend=1
        tempClientToCheck=$clientToCheck
        echo the temp client to check is: $tempClientToCheck
        clientToCheck+=_$numToAppend
        echo  the client to check is: $clientToCheck
        echo try number $numToAppend
        sleep 20
        while [[ $checkClient != *"$tempStr"* ]]; do

        #       let "numToAppend+1"
                ((++numToAppend))
                clientToCheck=$tempClientToCheck
                echo the client to check in the loop before appending  is: $clientToCheck
                clientToCheck+=_$numToAppend
                echo the client to check in the loop after appending is: $clientToCheck
                echo try number $numToAppend
                sleep 20

        done
        clientToCreate=$clientToCheck
        echo the client to create is $clientToCreate
}

#main
isClientExist
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        fixClientName
fi
```

Comment: You have several problems here: for one, `let "numToAppend+1"` doesn't do what you think it does: it only returns success. Instead, you probably want `((++numToAppend))`. Also, your line `clientToCheck+=_$numToAppend` will keep on appending: so before the `while` loop you have `clientToCheck` that expands to `irabinowitz_tlv-cc-lx64_806_1`, then, in the `while` loop you'll have `irabinowitz_tlv-cc-lx64_806_1_2`, `irabinowitz_tlv-cc-lx64_806_1_2_3`, etc. (assuming `numToAppend` gets incremented properly). Your design is also really weird.

Comment: Can you suggest another design ?

Comment: First fix the errors I mentioned and see if it helps.

Comment: Also in `fixClientName` you're never calling `isClientExist`.

Comment: I fixed it, it's still an infinity loop, it shouldn't go inside the loop because if you can see i'm appending the _1 before the loop, it's weird

Comment: Can you show the content of `tempStr`?

Comment: `tempStr="doesn\'t exist"`

Comment: In a previous comment I wrote: _Also in `fixClientName` you're never calling `isClientExist`._

Comment: i'm calling this function 
`#main
isClientExist
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        fixClientName
fi`

Comment: But in `fixClientName`, the variable `checkClient` is never updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not backslash-escape the <kbd>'</kbd> in:

```
tempStr="doesn\'t exist"
```

That will never match the string you expect, so `[[ $checkClient != *"$tempStr"* ]];` will always succeed.

It won't match, because inside a double-quoted string, `\'` is, literally, <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>. So the backslash would have to be in the message for the match to succeed.

Use one of the following:

```
tempStr="doesn't exist"
tempStr=doesn\'t\ exist
```

Comment: @user3502786: You should learn how to use function parameters (`$1`, `$2`, ...) and local variables. And also, remember that `if statement;`  tests whether  `statement` succeeds or fails, so there is no need to play games with `[[` and `$?` if you just want to know if a command succeeded or failed. But all of that belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user3502786 if it “works” it's because `isClientExist` succeeds and the `if` branch is never executed. In a case where `isClientExist` fails, you'll run into an infinite loop since, as I said in a comment, your function `fixClientName` never updates `checkClient`, so you'll still get an infinite loop in that case.

Comment: I could place the `fixClientName` function inside the `isClientExist` function

Comment: The `while` loop still not working, it's never exisitng from the program, any idea how to solve it ?